# Haproxy: active-active

Tags: haproxy

I am using haproxy for load balancing using backend rabbitmq server.

```
 vrrp_script chk_haproxy {           # Requires keepalived-1.1.13
        script "killall -0 haproxy"     # cheaper than pidof
        interval 2                      # check every 2 seconds
        weight 20                        # add 2 points of prio if OK
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
        interface enp2s0
    lvs_sync_daemon_inteface enp2s0
        state     BACKUP
        virtual_router_id 51
        priority 101                    # 101 on master, 100 on backup
    advert_int        1
        unicast_src_ip    192.168.0.38

     unicast_peer
 {

        192.168.0.41

 }

        virtual_ipaddress {
            192.168.0.100

        }
        track_script {
            chk_haproxy
        }
}

vrrp_instance VI_2 {
    interface         enp2s0
    state             BACKUP
    priority          100
    virtual_router_id 61
    advert_int         1
    unicast_src_ip    192.168.0.38

    unicast_peer 
    {

        192.168.0.41
    }

    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.0.101
    }

    track_script {
        chk_haproxy
    }


}
```

I have used this configuration in my code in keepalived.conf file. Is it possible to create the same configuration on another node? I want to configure haproxy active-active.

Comment: im unclear on what you mean by access remotely. do you mean listen on any? is it over the internet/local? if you could provide a snippet of your haproxy.cfg then we might be able to help...the question is a bit broad to be honest

Comment: how to configure haproxy active-active using keepalived?

Comment: please edit your question to reflect this...please make it more clear and include an example or code or config or something. Your question seems to be unrelated to your comment, im not trying to be mean, just trying to help but need some more info